Is $c = \frac{\sqrt 3}{4} \frac{\pi}{4} \prod_{p = 2 \mod 3} \sqrt{\frac{p^2}{p^2-1}} \prod_{q = u^2 + 3 v^2} \sqrt{\frac{q^2}{q^2-1}}$?
Consider the sum of $2$ squares and Gauss circle problem
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_circle_problem
and also
The Landau-Ramanujan Constant that relates to the sum of 2 squares. See : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau%E2%80%93Ramanujan_constant
Now I got a bit confused.
Here is why ;
If I want to estimate the (analogue) number of Eisenstein numbers $a^2 - ab + b^2$ smaller than a given integer $r$.
I wonder if I can just use the Landau estimate and simply change the primes $1 \mod 4$ into $1 \mod 3$ and $u^2 + 3 v^2$ and also add a factor $\frac{\sqrt 3}{4}$ because the triangle is smaller than the square by that ratio ; and say something like
$$\Pi_3(r) = \frac{c r}{\sqrt{\ln(r)}}$$
with
$$c = \frac{\sqrt 3}{4} \frac{\pi}{4} \prod_{p = 2 \mod 3} \sqrt{\frac{p^2}{p^2-1}} \prod_{q = u^2 + 3 v^2} \sqrt{\frac{q^2}{q^2-1}}$$
Or is it much more complex than that ?

I especially doubt the sqrt part since it seems that for $\mod 3$ there are more than $50 $% primes , in contrast to $1 \mod 4$ for the gaussians ...

$3$ is also an eisenstein prime, but ok , the question is clear.
